# Unity RegisterInstance on runtime (Not from Config file)

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container

I have a wcf service which provide a main configuration to all the other services in the system.

According to the configuration, I would like to create an instance (RegisterInstance\Type) at runtime.

I found only samples for how to do it by a configuration file.

I want to recieve the type from my configuration service.
All the types which I can get from the service are inherit from the same interface.

How can I do it without configuration file?

Thanks

Comment: The only solution I think of is to recieve from the configuration service an assembly path of the type that I want load. By reflection loading the assemly and to do RegisterType according to that. What do you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service has to send back enough info for you to be able to perform a registration then you will need to pass back the fully qualified type name including the assembly name and then you can call `Type.GetType` to get hold of the type object which you can then pass into `RegisterType`

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I think its a good idea to use a WCF service to send configuration information across the wire in the way you plan to do it.

1. On the client side you would need to start a client (which needs to be configured correctly)
2. Call the "configuration service" and take whatever information you get from there and
3. Try to make sense of it in a local context (find types in assemblies that you might not even have in your local scope etc.).
4. Configure a local instance of your UnityContainer and then
5. resolve your object graph and start your application/service

Not a straight forward solution IMHO.

But if you want to stick with that setup: why not send the config xml directly? It's even possible to stream the xml if you need to.